# Iphone 6 email reverts to 1970

Tags: email, iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6 on iOS 8.4.

My problem is that the emails keep getting set back to 1970 and are blank. This happens every single day and I have to wait hours for it too fully sync again.

I have tried reloading the phone, removing and re-adding the email, soft reset, hard reset.

This issue has been happening to me for the last few months and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: What mail app are you using? The default provide by Apple or a third party app?  If third party specifically which one?  Also what specific email service you using? Apple, gmail, yahoo etc?

Comment: Im using the default mail app with an exchange account.

Comment: If you haven't alreay, I'd try turning off Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calenders > Organize by thread.    Also you have a pretty specific diagnosis involving 1970, but you didn't tell use how you arrived it that, Where do you see 1970?

Comment: i see it over the whole mailbox every email changes to 01/01/1970 No sender no subject this message has no contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the resolution was to turn off the background app refresh in settings then general